# Checking a checkbox and applying the style to the corresponding input value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a todo list in vanilla JavaScript. Right now, I'm trying to apply a style to a todo when the corresponding checkbox is checked.

```
toDoContainer.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("checkbox")) {
      let toDo = tgt.closest("input").classList.contains("input");
      if (toDo.value !== "") {
          toDo.style.opacity = "50%";
      }
    }
  });
```

As it stands, nothing is happening visibly and I'm not getting an error.

I'm using the closest() method because the checkbox and the todo are both inputs that are right next to eachother in the DOM.

Before I was using this code -

```
allCheckboxes.forEach(box => {
    box.addEventListener("change", () => {
        if (box.checked) {
            for (let toDo = 0; toDo < allToDos.length; toDo++) {
                if (allToDos[toDo].value) {
                    allToDos[toDo].style.textDecoration = "line-through";
                    allToDos[toDo].style.opacity = "50%";
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log("cat");
            for (let toDo = 0; toDo < allToDos.length; toDo++) {
                if (allToDos[toDo].value) {
                    allToDos[toDo].style.textDecoration = "none";
                    allToDos[toDo].style.opacity = "100%";
                }
            }
        }
    })
})
```

I was able to apply the styles to the inputs but only when the first checkbox in the node list was checked. Checking the checkbox also applied the styles to all of the todos in the DOM, not just the corresponding one which is what I want.

Another quirk that I've just noticed is that when I look at dev tools to see if it's logging the checkboxes it shows an empty node list - [] when there are multiple checkboxes visible.

```
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(allCheckboxes);
});
```

How can I apply styling to only the corresponding todo when a checkbox is checked?

*** EDIT - https://codepen.io/harri-greeves/pen/LYLEKNj ***

Comment: Can you share a code pen/code sand box with including the html markup as well?

Comment: I've just shared the codepen link above.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using the closest() method because the checkbox and the todo are both inputs that are right next to each other in the DOM.

The closest method searches the element itself and then it searches the element's ancestors, moving up the dom tree.

I don't think `.closest` can be used to target siblings.

https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: That would explain a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on line:

`const allCheckboxes = toDoContainer.querySelectorAll("[type=checkbox]");`

`querySelector` returns not living html collection.
It means that it will not include dynamically added todos.

The better way is to listen parent node: `todoContainer` and then manipulate state.

Comment: Where did your previous solution go? I was reading it but it's no longer here?

Comment: Previous solution was out of context. Idk if I can bring it back :D

Comment: It looked pretty useful to me. I was going to use it lmfao

Comment: @HarrisonGreeves take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68933152/revisions

Comment: I've updated the code pen with the event delegation strategy. I'm still having a hard time accessing the input value when the corresponding checkbox is clicked. Also, why is it better to have CSS classes for todo states?

Comment: @HarrisonGreeves the problem now is on line 141.
As I mentioned before, `toDo` variable now contains Boolean.
To select the text input that is the sibling to the checkbox, you' ll need following code:
`const toDo = tgt.parentNode.querySelector('.input')`;

`element.closest()` works another way, and `.contains` method isn't actually selector :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236469/discussion-between-capchuck-and-harrison-greeves).

Answer (score 0):

add this function

```
function ChangeOpacity() {
let checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");
  let input = document.getElementsByClassName("input");
  for (let i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
   checkbox[i].addEventListener("change",()=>{
     if (checkbox[i].checked == true) {
       if (input[i].value) {
         input[i].style.opacity = "50%"
         input[i].style.textDecoration = "line-through"
       }
       else{
        input[i].style.opacity = "100%"
        input[i].style.textDecoration = "none"
       }
     } else {
      if (input[i].value) {
        input[i].style.opacity = "50%"
        input[i].style.textDecoration = "line-through"
      }
      else{
       input[i].style.opacity = "100%"
       input[i].style.textDecoration = "none"
      }
     }
   

   })
    
  }
}
ChangeOpacity()
```

and then call this function to the `createToDo` function
everything should work fine and its cleaner this way